# Image carousel and misaligned in ie

Tags: html, css

I have created a website but seems having  some issues with IE7 as follows

1. there are two links "How it works" and "View sample report" at first section(With green BG)- Bottom-right, Which are misaligned
2. Image carousel - I have given style `Overflow: hidden` to selector "nbs-flexisel-inner" But still its showing outside images in it, `Overflow: hidden` isn't working its working fine in FF and other browsers

**HERE IS LINK :**  http://products.jombay.com/

Comment: its overflow: hidden with lowercase o

Comment: the website looks fine in IE 8 and up

Comment: Its working fine in ie8 but problem is with IE7

Comment: @mohamedrias - its lowercase only :) in firebug you can see it :)

Comment: Am downloading IE7 portable to check, wait a bit ;)

Comment: @mohamedrias - Waiting for same, Kindly do it :)